# Display data labels and connector lines to the right side of the pie chart - highcharts

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I am new to using highcharts. i am looking for a way to display the data labels and the connector lines to the right side of the chart below.
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-datalabels-connectorshape-function

in the above graph , if i try using the position axes for dataLabels, only the labels are shifted to the right , i want a way to display both the lines and labels to the right side of the graph,
i am not sure how to override the `connectorShape` method to achieve this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Highcharts Series `afterTranslate` event and modify `half` and `labelPosition.alignment` point's properties. For example:

```
(function(H) {
  H.addEvent(H.Series, 'afterTranslate', function(e) {
    const series = e.target;

    series.points.forEach(point => {
      point.half = 0;
      point.labelPosition.alignment = 'left';
    });
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vqdt4hjy/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Thank you , i may have to modify the solution such that the connector lines do not pass through the slices. But this solution really helps!

Comment: @ppotaczek how to make like 50% of labels on left and 50% on right

Comment: Hi @Akshay Shrivastav, This is the default behaviour, example: https://jsfiddle.net/wL7c9h5p/ Please create a new question with `highcharts` tag if you want to achieve a different result.

Answer (score 0):

An update to @ppotaczek answer, i added below if an else condition

```
if ( index === 0 || index > 5 ) {
    point.half = 0;
    point.labelPosition.alignment = 'left';
} else {
    point.half = 1;
    point.labelPosition.alignment = 'right';
}
```

Highcharts might provide this a default behavior but this worked for me perfectly since I had to display only a dataset of 10.

So I tried to display 50% on the left and 50% on right. Since the first index will have the highest value i gave a condition `index === 0` to make sure that it does not over the annotation line on the left side and display just beside it

PN: Might be useful for someone